# FluentAssertions Comparing two list of different type

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I wonder if there is a way to compare two lists of different types. I found this method:

```
        public AndConstraint<TAssertions> Equal(IEnumerable<T> expectation, Func<T, T, bool> predicate, string because = "", params object[] reasonArgs)
        {
          this.AssertSubjectEquality<T>((IEnumerable) expectation, predicate, because, reasonArgs);
          return new AndConstraint<TAssertions>((TAssertions) this);
        }
```

I am looking for something like:

```
    public AndConstraint<TAssertions> Equal<U>(IEnumerable<T> expectation, Func<T, U, bool> predicate, string because = "", params object[] reasonArgs)
    {
      this.AssertSubjectEquality<T,U>((IEnumerable) expectation, predicate, because, reasonArgs);
      return new AndConstraint<TAssertions>((TAssertions) this);
    }
```

I tried to make an extension method but method **AssertSubjectEquality** is protected and does not support a second type.

Comment: Not sure if I understand exactly what you want. You have two different lists of different generic types, and you want to test a predicate against each entry in order? So maybe something like this? `list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }).Should().Equal(zippedInput => zippedInput.A == "something" && zippedInput.B == "somethingElse");`? Beyond that, since FluentAssertions is open source, you can always download it and add to it for your usage. I've done this and haven't had any significant issues adding to it.

Comment: You got it, your code snipped with a slight modification worked `list.Zip(monitoringObjects, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }).Should().Contain(x=> x.A.Id == x.B.Id);`
Although it is not very efficient due I am using `Contain` that works for disordered lists.  Maybe @DennisDoomen may have a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without copying the `AssertSubjectEquality` and `AssertCollectionsHaveSameCount` methods of the `CollectionAssertions` class along with it.

Instead, I would suggest you fork the repository and send me a Pull Request in which you change the generic parameters of those two methods from `<T>` to `<T, U>` and add your method to the `GenericCollectionAssertions`. I'll make it part of v3.3.